# qlik sense capability api 10000 limit

Tags: qliksense, hypercube

We've reached the limit for hypercubes and need to extract more than 10000 (data points - I used this term for lack of words to describe the individual cell that the API sends over 10000 is the max when you multiply width and height of your initial fetch) using the capability API.  has anyone been able to get the next page for hypercubes? note that our requirement is for mashups not extensions.
we did a work around but it required us to break our dataset and it takes a little longer.
makes you think, since Qlik is a data analytics tool there should be a way to get all of your data.  in an era where we process millions if not billions of records, 10000 data points (not even records) is miniscule.

I should also volunteer that the app we are using this for is for stock analysis and they want to see trends and require to see information on individual points as tooltips.  with the number of dimensions and measures we pass (total of 7 times the number of stocks - about 20 = 140) we are constricted to only 70 days (10000/140).

we are using qliksenseserver 11.24.4
Qlik Sense November 2017 Patch 2

Comment: Sense is a tool for make dashboards... is bad idea to show 10.000 data points in a dashboard where the objetive is that the users could obtain good information, you dont need qlik try on demand solution.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  I edited my question to attempt at some clarifications